# How to clone some part inside the repository without cloning the whole in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket.org

I want to make a repository inside the bitbucket however the structure that I am planning is so complicated..

I planned the structure to be like this

```
 MAIN_REPOSITORY

    REPOSITORY1

    REPOSITORY2

    REPOSITORY3
```

Inside the MAIN_REPOSITORY, there are also lists of repository. The reason behind is that  each repository in MAIN_REPOSITORY can only be access by a specific user so User from Repository1 cannot access REPOSITORY2 and REPOSITORY3, and vice versa. And if there is a problem in REPOSITORY1 the user will only clone the REPOSITORY1 not the MAIN_REPOSITORY.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 4 separate BitBucket repositories for this. The main repository can use *submodules* to link the child repositories (although that feature is not always the best option). In any case, the user will need to choose which individual repositories to clone.

Git primarily works with commits and branches (series of commits). Each commit captures all files in a repository; if you have access to a commit, you're assumed to have access to all files it references.

This means that read/clone access is always assigned per repository, or per branch (in some hosting services), but never per subdirectory. (Write access can be more flexible.)